# Compact set of a set $K$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Show that $K := \{x \in C[0,1] : x(0) \in [-3,4], |x(t)-x(s)| \leq d
 |t^2-s^2|, \forall t,s \in C[0,1]\}$ is compact.

I already know that $C[0,1]$ is a compact set. So it is only necessairy to show that $K$ is closed.

Is anyone is able to prove it or give me a good hint?

Comment: But $C[0,1]$ isn't compact space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Say that you have a sequence $x_n\to x$ such that $x_n(0) \in [-3,4]$ and $|x_n(t)-x_n(s)| \leq d  |t^2-s^2|$ for all $t$ and $s$ (you mean in $[0,1]$), for each $n$.

What happens in these two properties if $n\to\infty$?

Comment: This sequence converge, but what it is the link with my question?

Comment: @TajMohamedBandalandabad: to show $K$ is closed, it suffices to show that the limit of any convergent sequence of points in $K$ lies in $K$.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think $C[0,1]$ isn't compact space (in $\sup$ metric)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\;\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset K\;$ is such that $\;x_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}x\;$ . We must show that $\;x\in K\;$.

By continuity:

$$x(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n(0)\in[-3,4]\;,\;\;\text{as this last is a closed interval}$$

Also, again by continuity, for all $\;t,s\in[0,1]\;$ , we have

$$|x(t)-x(s)|=|\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x_n(t)-x_n(s)\right)|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n(t)-x_n(s)|\le\lim_{n\to\infty}d|t^2-s^2|=d|t^2-s^2|$$

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think $C[0,1]$ isn't compact space (in $\sup$ metric)